# UISearchBar linked with a UISearchDisplayController in the header of a UITableView in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` linked with a `UISearchDisplayController` in the header of a `UITableView` in `iOS7`.

I set the `UISearchBar` with the style minimal. When the `searchdisplaycontroller` shows his table it has the behavior of the picture below. The table is scrolling above the searchbar. When I switch the style of the tableview to Prominent the table scrolls under the searchbar as expected.

Is this a bug or this behavior is expected?

[image: UITableView with UISearchBar style minimal]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text isn't floating above the search bar, it's going below. Minimal style doesn't provide a background so this is expected. It will, however, provide a background during activation if there is a navigation bar present (Minimal style really wants to be over either no content or blurred content).

You are free to add your own custom background if you'd like.

Comment: I added a white background. It works partially, the status bar continues transparent. Look at Music app to a example.

Comment: Did you add a background for UIBarPositionTopAttached as well as UIBarPositionTop?

Comment: Thank you very much. The code that works: `[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]`;

Answer (score 3):

Try with
 *self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;*
in viewDidLoad method. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue may for the `Auto-Layout` or `Auto-Resizing`. Just check in the nib file in insppector view.

Comment: I disabled the Auto-Layout and it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make the x=0 and y=0 for search bar and for tableview x=0 and y=44 , now you will get the tableview below the searchbar.